# Checking class types in a list box

Tags: c#, types, listbox

I am building a GUI where I have two classes, Student and Graduate. Graduate is a child class of Student. The user will fill out forms to add the student to the list. In order to add said information to a view form I need to check what the selected item's type is. I have tried

`if(view_list.selectedItem.GetType == Student)`

but it doesn't work. How would I be able to check the type of the selected item?

Comment: What is view_list?

Comment: Can you elaborate `it doesn't work` ?

Comment: view_list is what I named my list box. When I say it doesn't work it says that Student is a type, which is not valid in this context.

Comment: @Professor_Arkansas Can you share the code of how you populate `view_list`? And what's purpose you are trying to solve by writing this code?

Comment: This is relatively easy (and much easier for you) to solve (than us)  by clicking on the `if`, pressing F9 so it goes red, pressing F5 and invoking whatever set of actions needed to make this code execute. VS will stop on the line with a yellow bar, then you can simply point to the selectedItem property to see a tooltip showing you *what type the variable is* and it's current value(s) which you can explore by expanding the tree. The same into is also shown in the Locals window, which doesn't disappear at the slip of a mouse.

Comment: Once you have found the property you can turn it into code using what you have discovered, eg you might see it's a course with many students; write `if((something.SelectedItem as Course).Students.First() is Graduate...)` - you can use `is` and `as` to perform readable casts of the code. Controls like listviews for example, might have SelectedValue return an `object` so you have to cast it back to what it truly is using `as` or `is Graduate g` if you want it casted to a reusable temp variable. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

Answer (score 1):

In short, you'll need to compare `XXX.GetType()` with `typeof(YOUR_TYPE)`.
[image: Example]

As for the reason, if you have ever stared at the IntelliCode tips provided by Visual Studio, you should see that the function `object.GetType()` returns `Type`
[image: IntelliCode for GetType()]

However, `Student` or any other primitive types like `int`, `string`, etc. has type of `class`
[image: IntelliCode for Student]

You can't compare two values with different types (in this case the left hand side is of `Type` but the right hand side is of `class`)

What `typeof()` does is to get the `Type` of a **class**.
[image: IntelliCode of typeof()]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems.
The `GetType` which you are trying to use is actually a method, not a property, so you need to call it as `GetType()`.

The next is that you need to use `typeof(Student)` to compare.

And if `view_list` is a Winforms ListView, then `SelectedItem` should start with uppercase S

So then you code should be.

```
if (view_list.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(Student))
{
   //Do your stuff
}
```